# Replicate the DOE Energy Flow chart?

Tags: chart-design

Is there a name for this type of material flow chart?

Are there any tools to automate or partially automate the creation of these charts? Or are these created manually in a program like Adobe Illustrator ?
[image]

https://flowcharts.llnl.gov/content/assets/images/energy/us/Energy_US_2018.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a sankey diagram.  You can read more about it [here](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/sankey.html).

Comment: And in specific this is an example of the subset of Sankey diagrams which is called an "alluvial chart" of memory serves. There's a list of SW for this kind of thing on the Sankey Diagram website (it's a .org I think) which has paid desktop apps, website based apps (both free and paid) and there is at least one iOS app for making these too.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please [edit] your question to add some information beyond the name of the type (e.g., as commented by Gerard Falla). As it stands, your answer relies a lot on that link.